# Set max width and max height of image from Picasso. It's not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, picasso

I'm trying to set the Set max width and max height of an image from Picasso but for some reason it is not working.

Here is my code:
`Picasso.with(this).load(imagePath).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageTest);`

This is my xml:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="42dp"
    android:maxHeight="42dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/imageTest"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

use resize

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imagePath).resize(42,42).transform(new CircleTransform().into(imageTest);
```

Comment: I was try it . It's not working . For example : One image with 512x512 pixel . If you using resize(42,42). It's not smaller. It's feels look so bad. How to for it smaller and look still good ?